# Creating a loop to import data from a csv file line by line, plot them and save each plot separately

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python so I'm still learning the details.

I've got a CSV file with 45 columns of data, the first column being the x-axis and columns 2-45 all being y-axes data. What I'm trying to do is import all of this data (line by line) and then make a plot for each y-axis column with the same x, so (x, y_1), (x, y_2) .... (x, y_45) and also save each plot separately as 1.png, 2.png...45.png.

I can do this with manually line by line with the following code:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

data = csv2rec('e.csv')
x = np.array([column[0] for column in data])
y_1 = np.array([column[1] for column in data])

plot( x, y_1, 'k-', label='1' )

lgd = legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.75), fontsize='xx-small')
#plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.gca().set_xlabel(r'$\lambda$($\AA$)')
ylabel( 'FUV-MAG(AB)' )
savefig('1.png', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

But of course this takes a while to do by hand. I know how to do a basic loop over a range of x and y columns to plot them, but I was wondering if any of you had any suggestions on how to perhaps create a loop to import, plot and save all the above plots at the same time.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with `csv2rec` yet so am not entirely familiar with its output (so the `range(1,len(column))` part may need tweaking but hopefully illustrates the fundamental principle), but have you tried something like this yet? (I would also try and avoid working with `from pylab import *` as it makes it hard to track where which function comes from)

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

data = csv2rec('e.csv')

for i in range(1,len(column)):
    x = np.array([column[0] for column in data])
    y_1 = np.array([column[i] for column in data])

    plot( x, y_1, 'k-', label='1' )

    lgd = legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.75), fontsize='xx-small')
    #plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.gca().get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    plt.gca().set_xlabel(r'$\lambda$($\AA$)')
    ylabel( 'FUV-MAG(AB)' )
    name=str(i)
    name+='.png'
    savefig(name, bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. As you mentioned, the `range(1,len(column))` did give a column not defined error (not sure why column would be undefined), but I put in the last column number in place of `len(column)` and it worked great. I'm still learning how to apply loops effectively and this was a great example to go by. Thanks a bunch!